# How to echo an output in a specific div

Tags: php, css, echo

I have a page full of products and when the page reloads after the add to cart button has been clicked i want to display a check mark next to the product that was added.
Using the rows and columns count i have assigned each product it's own class, for example

```
<div class = "location12">
```

I passed the location via post when the add to cart button is pressed so i can tell which div the button press was from and i can then use that data as an identifier.
I can get the page to scroll back to this position by referencing the div, but i'm struggling to get the image to only display on that one product. It will display on that product and then every product after it because it echoes on every time it loops after the first output.

Already added to the individual product page, but they want the same function as here: http://confettibox.ch/1-NEWSTORE/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=576_578&products_id=1265&language=en

on this page here:
http://confettibox.ch/1-NEWSTORE/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=4_586

Add to cart button submit is coded here, and you can see where i added the hidden field to pass the id of the div

```
$lc_button= '<div class="back">' . zen_draw_form_prod_list('cart_quantity', preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string), 'post', 'enctype="multipart/form-data"') . '</div><div class="back qty_bg"><input type="text" name="cart_quantity" value="' . (zen_get_buy_now_qty($listing->fields['products_id'])) . '" maxlength="6" size="4" /><br />' . zen_draw_hidden_field('products_id', $listing->fields['products_id']) . zen_draw_hidden_field('div_id', $colcount.$rows) . '</div><div class="forward">' . zen_image_submit('button_add.jpg', BUTTON_IN_CART_ALT) . '</form></div><br class="clearBoth">';
```

I added the $_POST result to a session var here:

```
$_SESSION['location'] = (int)$_POST['div_id'];
```

And then used:

```
if ($messageStack->size('listing') > 0 && $_SESSION['location'] == $colcount.$rows) {
```

so that the messageStack output (success checkmark) would only display for that one product... except it displays for everything after it too :|

Products are output using this code:

```
if (PRODUCT_LISTING_LAYOUT_STYLE == 'columns') {
  $lc_text = implode('<br />', $product_contents);

  $list_box_contents[$rows][$column] = array('params' => 'class="centerBoxContentsProducts centeredContent back featured'. $column .'"' . ' ' . 'style="width:235px;"',
                                             'text'  => $lc_text = '
                     <div class="prod_table">
                     <div class="prod_image"><a href="' . zen_href_link(zen_get_info_page($listing->fields['products_id']), 'cPath=' . (($_GET['manufacturers_id'] > 0 and $_GET['filter_id']) > 0 ?  zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($_GET['filter_id']) : ($_GET['cPath'] > 0 ? zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($_GET['cPath']) : zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($listing->fields['master_categories_id']))) . '&products_id=' . $listing->fields['products_id']) . '">' . zen_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $listing->fields['products_image'], $listing->fields['products_name'], IMAGE_PRODUCT_LISTING_WIDTH, IMAGE_PRODUCT_LISTING_HEIGHT, 'class="listingProductImage"') . '</a></div>
                     <div class="prod_name"><a href="' . zen_href_link(zen_get_info_page($listing->fields['products_id']), 'cPath=' . (($_GET['manufacturers_id'] > 0 and $_GET['filter_id']) > 0 ?  zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($_GET['filter_id']) : ($_GET['cPath'] > 0 ? zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($_GET['cPath']) : zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($listing->fields['master_categories_id']))) . '&products_id=' . $listing->fields['products_id']) . '">' . $listing->fields['products_name'] . '</a></div>
                     <div class="prod_price back">'. zen_get_products_display_price($listing->fields['products_id']) .'</div>
                     <div class = "location'. $colcount.$rows .'">'.$success.' </div>
                     <div class="prod_content forward">'. $the_button .'</div>
                     </div>
                     ');
      $column ++;
  $colcount=$column;

  if ($column >= PRODUCT_LISTING_COLUMNS_PER_ROW) {
    $column = 0;
    $rows ++;

  }
}
// End of Code fragment for Column Layout (Grid Layout) option in add on module
$listing->MoveNext();
```

$success is where i want the check to be output.

How can i echo the success message to only 'location12' ?
Is it even possible?

Comment: Not enough info here to help. You might need Javascript here though.

Comment: You need to show your PHP, a link to a test site wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: @MrUpsidown If you tell me what info you need i can give it to you. Little point pasting the entire php file as much is irrelevant

Comment: You might want to transfer your selected location via SESSION instead of a POST. An attacker could send his own location and show checks at any product he wanted. Not a huge attack, but a possible problem with legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted much code but I'll try answering.
You can do it either with Javascript or PHP.
With Javascript/jQuery you can set the background image of any div you want:

```
$('.location12').css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");
```

With PHP you need to count your iterations and only echo the image on $index==12.
I do not know if you are using foreach, for, while or any other method. 
Assuming it is a foreach loop you can do the following:

```
$index = 1;
foreach ($products as $product) {
if ($index == 12) {echo "<img src=''/>"}
$index++;
}
```

As you can see, the jQuery method is easier.

Hope this helps!